# can't assign to operator - python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, syntax-error, nan, missing-data

I am trying to fill  all the null values of a feature in a data frame using the SGDClassifier.
But before that I am making a train and test dataset having the index data of all the null and non null values

But I am getting this error -

```py
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

This is my code -

```py
missing_idx = []

for i in range(data2.shape[0]):
  if data2['Rupee/sq.ft'][i] is None:
    missing_idx.append(i)

#independent parameters
missing_/sqft_X_train = np.array([ [data2['Bedrooms'][i],data2['Bathrooms'][i],data2['Condtion'][i],data2['Purchase Type'][i],data2['Real Estate Regulation Act'][i] ] for i in range(data2.shape[0]) if i not in missing_idx ])

#dependent parameters
missing_/sqft_y_train = np.array([ [data2['Rupee/sq.ft'][i],data2['Price (Lakhs)'][i],data2['Area'][i] ]for i in range(data2.shape[0]) if i not in missing_idx])

missing_/sqft_X_test = np.array([ [data2['Bedrooms'][i],data2['Bathrooms'][i],data2['Condtion'][i],data2['Purchase Type'][i],data2['Real Estate Regulation Act'][i] ] for i in range(data2.shape[0]) if i in missing_idx ])
```

Can anyone help me out with this?
Any suggestions?

Is there any other method I can use to fill the null values of a specific featur as they are dependent other features?

Comment: What do you want `x/y = ...`  to do? How does it make sense to assign the result of a division to something else?

Comment: @timgeb there is no division

Comment: Python disagrees. `/` is the division operator.

Comment: / is in just the name of the column heading. it is not used as an operator here,
what i am doing is different @timgeb

Comment: Why are you being so stubborn? I'm telling you that you cannot use `/` in a name. Python refuses because it's the division operator. So either you change your variable names or you keep your SyntaxError.

Comment: thanks, sorry I didn't get it the first time  @timgeb

Comment: No worries happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )

You can replace / with underscore